# How to do a gradle tasks with info switch

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to follow instructions that say to compile with `gradle tasks --info`.

Where do I run this?

Is there a way to do this from inside Android Studio? If not then I wouldn't know how to point it to my project. I was hoping there would be a combo box I could set to the info verbosity level and just redo my build, but I can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--info` is a command line switch. You will need to run this from the command shell.

See also: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html